# Where is Grails 2.4.5 lib folder

Tags: grails

We have some libraries that are not in our local repository and for some reason, they will not appear there soon. SO I need to add some libraries manually to our local development etc. environments. Where is the lib folder of the framework to manually put our internal jar libraries? I installed the grails using sdkman to my mac.

Is it /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/lib ?

Comment: It depends on your project configuration. Can you post your project build configuration file/s?

Comment: I am new to grails but I dont see a lib property or a related one in my BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: please accept the answer if that solves your problem

Comment: Can you also add an example of an exact path to the libs folder your answer? Is it anywhere or related to the grails installation etc. So people will know where to put the jar files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a local `.jar` file as a dependency using this code in your `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
/*
 * prj/
 *   grails-app/
 *     conf/
 *       BuildConfig.groovy
 *   lib/
 *     your_lib.jar
 */
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/your_lib.jar')
}
```

The `lib` directory must be located inside the root directory of your project.

If you want to include all `.jar` file inside a directory use this:

```
dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This is a gradle configuration file, you can find [gradle file dependencies documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).

For Grails take a look at [2.4.5 specific dependency resolution documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution).